# Getting catalog of .bat file and creating directory in that

Tags: batch-file

I'm new in batch programming I want to write BAT program that:

- Getting catalog of .bat file
- Create in that catalog directory named "Data"
- Echo second argument of BAT program

How to do it?

Comment: What do you mean with : `Getting catalog of .bat` file. Did you already try (code) something ?

Comment: Questions describing your requirements and asking someone to write the code for you or explain how to write the code are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please identify a specific problem or question about programming. Include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differ from the desired results, and any error messages you receive. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page and [this advice on asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
rem Getting catalog of .bat file
set catt=%~dp0
rem Create in that catalog directory named "Data"
if not exist "%catt%\data\" mkdir "%catt%\data\"
rem Echo second argument of BAT program
echo %2
exit /b 0
```